# How do I get the Smartware tools working on the HDD itself?

Tags: installation, external-hard-drive, disk-utility

WD My Passport 0740 - WD Smartware

I'm posting because I have a problem with the Smartware that was IN the HDD. A friend of mine accidentally deleted the folder Smartware (that I created and placed all the utilities in) and now all I can download is the software that installs on the computer. Is there any possible way to get the original utilities that were in the hard drive working FROM the HDD itself?

Answer (score 0):

The software on the drive is the software you can download from Western Digital.

Was there something else you put in that folder?  If so, there are various Undelete programs that may assist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw that its the same thing but the Smartware on the HDD ran from the HDD and not from the computer. Plus there were some back-up utilities and things on the HDD that don't come with the downloaded version of Smartware I got...